# Error while connecting to Database Server from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Recently, while trying to connect to any SQL Server Database from SQL Server Management Studio, I am getting an error - `Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' not found (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)`

I tried updating to the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio but there is no change.

The full error stack is as below:

```
===================================

Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' not found (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ServiceProvider.GetService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.NavigationService.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.NavigationService.GetView(String urnPath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.<GetColumnsFromNavigationService>d__11.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.AddFields(List`1 list, IEnumerable`1 fields, IDictionary`2 allValidFields, AddFieldsFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.GetParentFields(INodeInformation source, Dictionary`2& allValidColumns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItemWithQuery(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, String urnQuery, Boolean registerBuilder, Boolean registerBuiltItems)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItem(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)
```

Any idea why this error is happening?

Comment: Could be permissions. Have you tried Run as Administrator to open it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yes. I had tried that. It is still giving the same error

Comment: Is it an expired trial version?

Comment: Considering that SSMS is free, and the OP said they updated to the latest version (SSMS 18.1) then there would be no trial period.

Comment: I have tried upgrading it to SSMS 18.2 version as well.

Answer (score 10):

What helped in my case... (version 17.9.1)

I have checked file:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\14.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

In there I have found the information that the directory:

```
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio
```

has not been found.
I have created it manually and... SSMS started working.

Yeah I know... It sounds crazy.

Comment: I had the same issue - this folder was missing. This was caused by "controlled folder access" (windows 10).

Comment: Great tip - I had to restart MSSMS and it worked like a dream.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had to add an additional folder called "ArchitectureExplorer" under C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\ArchitectureExplorer

Answer (score 1):

@Marek Malczewski is right, thank you sir!

I too looked at the log files and fixed it the same way, here is a screenshot for your confirmation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\Users\ <\users>\Documents
and create a new folder with name **SQL Server Management Studio** then Restart MSQL server as well.

Hopefully your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Install .NET 4.8.
I've had exactly the same issue and it worked for me.

Comment: It did not work. I tried installing the .net runtime. I am still seeing the same error