# Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' not found (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hi everyone please help me.I got this error message when I login sql servermanagement studio and I expand database,this message show

> Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' not found (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)"

I cannot get access to my local database and even
remote database.And then I repaired both server and sql management studio.But error still occure.

Here is error message screen capture.

[image: ErrorMessage Img]

**Note**-(I use Sql Server 2014 Express edition because my PC is window 7)

Comment: Windows 7 has been entirely unsupported for some time now; you should really be upgrading.

Comment: Also, why are you running SQL Server 2014 RTM? What do you have against updating (both your operating system and your applications)?

Comment: Does your version of SSMS support connections to SQL 2014?

Comment: I download and install both sql server and ssms from this link."https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299"

Comment: In your account's Documents folder create a folder named "SQL Server Management Studio" and then try relaunching SSMS. ref: [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62465350/390122).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while connecting to Database Server from SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588926/error-while-connecting-to-database-server-from-sql-server-management-studio)